# Issue with strange char and md5

Tags: sql, sql-server, md5

I have a column in the database which apears to contain '/'  data type of the column is nvarchar(4000).   The problem that im having is that when i do a `hashbytes('MD5',page)` on the column the results are diffrent then `hashbytes('MD5','/')` .  After a bit of digging i found after casting the column to varchar(4000) that the column actualy contains '/?' so theres some weird char in there thats causing my md5 to calcuate diffrently.

```
select id,
       profileid,
       cast( page as varchar(4000)) as pageVarchar,
       hashbytes('MD5',cast( page as varchar(4000)) ) as pageVarcharMd5,       
           cast( page as nvarchar(4000)) as pageNvarchar,
       hashbytes('MD5',cast( page as nvarchar(4000)) ) as pagenVarcharMd5,     
       hashbytes('MD5',cast('/' as varchar(4000))) as md5slashVarchar,
       hashbytes('MD5',cast('/' as nvarchar(4000))) as md5slashnvarchar
from dpage
where (page = '/')
```

As you can see i can where page = '/' and get my row back.  But when i start trying to hash it the results are diffrent.

```
id  profileid   pageVarchar pageVarcharMd5                      pageNvarchar    pagenVarcharMd5                    md5slashVarchar                     md5slashnvarchar
40  34896748    /?          0xE01DD917A616858C7BA62C0F85F63110  /‎               0x35F46F45AB74285BB888711367F0A86E 0x6666CD76F96956469E7BE39D750CC7D9  0x6B92BB2C65A19276DF9388E936CCD25C
```

Has anyone run across this problem before?  If so do you have a solution or can just explain what is going?.  I have a work around for it so at this point its more for curiosity sake that i'm asking.

Comment: you will always have different md5 sums from the same string when comparing varchar and nvarchar. this is because nvarchar is coded as multibyte charachters wheras varchar is only 8-bit. i suspect it is because the md5s will be calculated from the binary representation of the string.

Comment: my point is that when i select the column from the table its value is /.  Yet its not / when that column is casted as a varchar its actualy /?  so there must be something else in that column that im not seeing.

Comment: have you tried using convert instead of cast? they are essentially different data types and using cast is just slapping on a different label. since nvarchar is multibyte, the `?` may just be the other byte representig `/` in nvarchar.

Comment: what does `cast( page as varbinary(max) )` output?